# Troubles With UIPageViewController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, segue, uipageviewcontroller

I've been having a terribly hard time trying to create a Tutorial flow for my app using swift...Here's what I want to do:
User comes to start screen which has button to allow them to "take the tour" This is Storyboarded and works fine.
User presses button, and tutorial appears from push segue. 
After tutorial user can go on to perform other functions.

I first tried to create the UIPageViewController by simply dragging it into the storyboard and attaching a class. That didn't work. So I found a tutorial that I used to create this:

```
import UIKit

class TutorialViewController: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

var pageController: UIPageViewController?
let pageAssets:[String] = ["blender.png", "click.png", "share.png"]
var currentIndex: Int = 0

// MARK: - View Lifecycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    pageController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
    pageController!.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height);
    pageController!.dataSource = self

    var initialViewController: PageContentViewController = self.viewControllerAtIndex(0)
    let viewControllers: NSArray = [initialViewController]

    pageController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    addChildViewController(self.pageController!)
    self.view.addSubview(pageController!.view)
    pageController!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// MARK: - DataSource protocol conformance
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    var idx: Int = (viewController as PageContentViewController).itemIndex

    if (idx == 0) {
        return nil
    }

    idx--

    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(idx)
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    var idx = (viewController as PageContentViewController).itemIndex

    if (idx > pageAssets.count){
        return nil
    }

    idx++

    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(idx)
}


func viewControllerAtIndex(index:Int) -> PageContentViewController {
    let childViewController:PageContentViewController = PageContentViewController()
    childViewController.itemIndex = index
    childViewController.imageName = pageAssets[index]
    currentIndex = index

    return childViewController
}


// MARK: - Navigation
func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return pageAssets.count
}

func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 0
}

/*
// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
} */
```

}

And here is the PageContentViewController:

```
import UIKit

class PageContentViewController: UIViewController  {

    @IBOutlet weak var testLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tutorialImageView: UIImageView!

    // MARK: - Variables
    @IBOutlet weak var contentImageView: UIImageView!
    var itemIndex: Int = 0

    //computed member which calls didSet that actually creates the UIImage that's displayed
    var imageName: String = ""{
        didSet {
            if let imageView = contentImageView {
                tutorialImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - View Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        contentImageView?.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
    }

}
```

So first, how do I get to this Class using a Segue, OR from my AppDelegate?

I know...long question, but I'm really outdone by trying to create a PageView intro. Any and all help is appreciated...

Comment: Did not get your point? you want your class during perform segue ? then had you try with prepareForSegue method?

Comment: @Jageen I know it's a little confusing. I want my initial ViewController, let's call it StartViewController to segue to TutorialViewController. But right now, I can't even get the TutorialViewController to show the screens it should swipe through.